# Url.RouteUrl returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm buiding a UrlHelper for a route
as in [best practices](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx#urlHelperRoute)

the problem is that the returned value is always null
when debugging in found that

Url.RouteUrl("x") return null

Url.RouteCollection["X"] return Route

i'm trying to do :

```
public static string Category(this UrlHelper helper, int Id, string category)
{
     return helper.RouteUrl("X", new {id = Id, category= category});
}
```

I can't see where I'm doing something wrong

Comment: In your Global.asax, are you actually registering a route named "X"?

Comment: yes there is a route registered as 
routes.MapRoute("X", "/category/{id}/{category}", new {controller="category", action= "List"})

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears that this is being caused because you did not specify a default value for {id} and {category} when registering your routes.

`Url.RouteUrl("x")` will return null because there's no value for id and category provided, and your route definition does not have a default.

I think that you will find if you update your route entry to specify a default value for id and category this will solve your problem. Alternatively, if you are sure to *always* provide a value for id and category, you can do without it.

As far as your actual Url helper method Category(), that *should* be working just fine as-is if you are providing a non-null or empty value for id and category. I literally copied the code and it works for me.

Comment: I have set all the defaults and I'm still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i was still running the mvc release candidate
I installed the mvc 1.0 and now it works fine